# What is the meaning of the number after Arithmetic shift?

Tags: binary, decimal, twos-complement

The question is come from here:

> A decimal number -100 stores into an 8 bits register using two's complement, What is the
>   decimal after the 3 bits right arithmetic shift?

The answers are `-13` and here is how it solves:

1. convert `-100` to binary `01100100`
2. two's complement `10011100`
3. right arithmetic shift `11110011`
4. two's complement again `00001101`

Quesiont:
 I do not understand the why the result gets from step 3, need to do the two's complement again, and the answer is `-13` not `13`.

Comment: right arithmetic shift should be just like dividing by 2. `-100 >> 1` should be `-50` I dont get how you got to `-13`. Are you sure `-13` is the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct conversion should be:

```
Decimal   = Binary 2's complement
-100      = 1001 1100
-100 >> 1 = 1100 1110 = -50
-100 >> 2 = 1110 0111 = -25
-100 >> 3 = 1111 0011 = -13
```

Commenting your steps, on-by-one:

> 1. convert `-100` to binary `01100100`

You are not converting `-100`. You are converting `100` to binary. Small correction, but very important.

> 2. two's complement `10011100`

This is correct, as we take a 2's complement of a number by inverting it and adding `1`.

```
inv(01100100) = 1001 1011
add one       = 1001 1100
```

> 3. right arithmetic shift `11110011`

To be 100% accurate I would say `right arithmetic shift three times`

> 4. two's complement again `00001101`

Here is where I think your question is...

So the result is `11110011` we all agree on that. The question here is what is `11110011` in decimal? I know 2 ways of doing the conversion. I will try to summarize them here.

**Method 1: Two's complement**

We know that `11110011` is a negative number because it's MSB is `1`. To find out what the value is we take the 2's complement. So we invert the value and add `1`.

```
inv(11110011) = 0000 1100
add 1         = 0000 1101
                ---------
convert to decimal     13
```

So, we know it was negative, and now we know the value. So `-13` is the answer.

**Method 2: Using weights**

We attribute a weight to each of the bits and we add them all together. All bits have a positive weight, except the MSB which has a negative weight.

```
Bit index    7  6   5  4  3  2  1  0
Weight    -128 64  32 16  8  4  2  1
```

So for our result, we have:

```
Bit index    7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
Weight    -128 +64 +32 +16  +8  +4  +2  +1
-------------------------------------------
-13          1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
          -128 +64 +32 +16  +0  +0  +2  +1

-128
+ 64
+ 32
+ 16
+  2
+  1
----
 -13
```

Both methods are valid and will give you the correct conversion at the end, it comes down to which conversion method you prefer.

If you have any doubts read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift).

Comment: Sorry, made the mistake, I corrected the question. Please take a look.